# How to Open device map in My iphone Application for Draw path between Source and Destination?

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I want to Open Device Map in My Iphone app for Draw path between Source and Destination, like below Image.

[image]

How to open Device Map in My Iphone app like above image?

Comment: http://iphonegeeksworld.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/drawing-routes-onto-mkmapview-using-unofficial-google-maps-directions-api/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489756/how-to-draw-a-route-between-my-current-location-to-desired-location-on-mkmapview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531889/how-to-route-between-two-addresses-using-the-new-ios-6-0-maps

Comment: Follow this ... i implemented this in one of my app  http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/show-route-from-current-location-to.html

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to open Maps app,

```
        NSString *url;

        if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
        {
            url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%@,%@&saddr=%@,%@",[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"],[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"],currentLat,currentLong];

        }
        else
        {
            url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=%@,%@&saddr=%@,%@",[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"],[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"],currentLat,currentLong];
        }
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        }
```

iOS 6.0 and above has Apple Map app for lower iOS version you have to open google map app. Here in url,

```
daddr=%@,%@&saddr=%@,%@
```

`daddr` is destination address and `saddr` is source address.